# MATLAB the greatest sum of sub vectors with "n" length of the original vector

Tags: matlab, loops

Working with MATLAB. I need to write a function called `m_s`, with `v` (vector) and n as input arguments and `summa` and index as the output arguments, the function should find the n consecutive elements in the given vector whose sum is the largest, and also should find the index of the first element of the n sequence. I have tried this but there's a problem when `summa` gets to the maximum, the problem with my code is that when it gets to the maximum sum, then `summa2` starts incrementing in a way different to expected, it gives a sum of non consecutive numbers. When the user gives a bigger `n` than the length of the vector, the function should return: `n=-1` and `summa = 0`, Also when n is the same number than `length(v)`, the function should return `n=1` and `summa = sum(v)`. This is my code

```matlab
function [summa index] = m_s(v,n)
    lv = length(v);
    times = lv - n; 
    if n > lv
        summa = 0;
        index = -1;
    elseif n == lv
        summa = sum(v);
        index = 1;
    else
        for i = 1:times
            sum1 = sum(v(i:n))
            sum2 = sum(v(i+1):(n+1))
            if sum1 < sum2
                summa = sum2;       
                index = i+1;
                n = n+1;           
            elseif sum1 > sum2         
                n = n+1;
            end                
        end        
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to sum `v(i:i+n-1)`, not `v(i:n)`.

Comment: Also, `sum2` has wrong parenthesis.